# How to use regex to perform a lazy match on timestamps

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to perform lazy matches on timestamps of the following format:

```
12:01 PM
12:02 PM
12:03 PM
```

Using the following matched all timestamps:

```
\d+:\d+ PM
```

How can I modify the expression to match only the first timestamp from the above? i.e.

```
12:01 PM
```

Comment: Add a `.*` to the end of the pattern to absorb all the remaining characters in the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your regex would match also 123:321 PM and would not match 03:20 AM, so I would suggest such regex: `\d\d:\d\d [PA]M`

Also, if you want only first match, you just access first matched value in object used to store regex results. I.e. You most probably use some programming language (what it is?) and you are using Regex API exposed by regex library in that language. Just make use of it.

Besides, if the begining of your example is also begining of whole text you might want to use `^\d\d:\d\d [PA]M`

I added `^` to match begining of a whole text, so it anchors match right where you want it: [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XPWbby/1) Note that you need to disable multiline flag.